# How to convert an NSString to an NSDate with time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert an `NSString` to an `NSDate` with time. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
 NSString *myDateIs= @"2012-07-14 11:30:40 AM ";
 NSDateFormatter* startTimeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [startTimeFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a "];
 NSDate*newStartTime = [startTimeFormat dateFromString:myDateIs];
```

The output is `2012-07-14 06:00:40 +0000`. The date is correct but the time is not correct.
How can I get the correct time? 
Thanks.

Comment: use this

NSString *myDateIs= @"2012-07-14 11:30:40 AM ";
    NSDateFormatter* startTimeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [startTimeFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a "];
    [startTimeFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate*newStartTime = [startTimeFormat dateFromString:myDateIs];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time you are getting is in GMT convert it into local time.

```
NSDateFormatter* local = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];        
[local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
[local setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];

NSString* localSTR = [local stringFromDate: newStartTime];
```

Answer (score 1):

Time Zone. The NSDate will store the time in terms of GMT. However your local time zone is probably quite different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the timezone.

```
NSString *myDateIs= @"2012-07-14 11:30:40 AM ";
NSDateFormatter* startTimeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
startTimeFormat.timeZone=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[startTimeFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate*newStartTime = [startTimeFormat dateFromString:myDateIs];
NSLog(@"%@", newStartTime);
```

Output:

```
 2012-07-14 11:30:40 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will work for you:

```
[startTimeFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa"];
[startTimeFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

You missed an a at the dateFormat and have to set the timeZone.